# Why do I get a compile error in this macro

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a copy/paste as values macro that involves a drop down menu. I think I have the "drop down" part, but I need Excel to copy/paste as values one row at a time before plugging in the next drop down value.

What I need help figuring out is do I have the 
1)"d8 = d" in the right order, should it be moved up
2) is the syntax for the copy/paste range correct?

3) how do I tell it to Copy/paste as values one row at a time?

Here is the sheet with the cells I want to copy/paste as values
[image]

Will this code give me what I want in terms of plugging in the dropdown, letting the formulas calc, and the copying and pasting one line at a time?

```
Sub Copy_Paste()
Sheets("MS Wall Summary Weekly View").Activate
    Dim vRws As Long, vRng As Range
    Dim d As Range, d8 As Range, Wst As Worksheet
    Dim vRng2 As Range, vRws2 As Long, i As Long

Set Wst = Worksheets("MS Wall Summary Weekly View")
Set d8 = Wst.Range("D8")

With Wst
   vRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set vRng = Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(vRws, "A"))
End With

For Each d In vRng.Cells

d8 = d
Sheets("Email").Activate
With ActiveSheet
    vRws2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(x1Up).Row
    For i = 8 To vRws2
        Set vRng2 = Range("U" & i & "AC" & i)
            vRng2.Copy
                vRng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

Next d
Next i
```

Comment: What are you attempting to do with `d8 = d`?

Comment: On another tab I have a drop down. Its in the same order as col. R in the picture. I want it to take each "d" and plug it into d8. This will run a bunch of sumifs, which will appear in the columns I took a picture of

Comment: In the future, please state where the error exists when this info is known

Comment: So then, If I want to Copy/paste one line at a time, will adding this in do that?vRng2.Copy
                vRng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
        
Next d
Next i

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about compile errors is that they tell you exactly where the error exists. You had typos and a invalid string build on the marked lines below

1. Error 1: `...End(x1Up)` (you swapped the number 1 with letter l).
2. Error 2: `Set vRng2 = Range (""U" & i:"AC"& i")`. You have double quotes around the `U` and you did not enclose the `:` inside quotes. You also left `i` inside the quotes. Please see correct method in code below

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Paste()
Sheets("MS Wall Summary Weekly View").Activate
    Dim vRws As Long, vRng As Range
    Dim d As Range, d8 As Range, Wst As Worksheet
    Dim vRng2 As Range, vRws2 As Long, i As Long

Set Wst = Worksheets("MS Wall Summary Weekly View")
Set d8 = Wst.Range("D8")

With Wst
   vRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set vRng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(vRws, "A"))
End With

For Each d In vRng.Cells

d8 = d
Sheets("Email").Activate
With ActiveSheet
    vRws2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row '< -- Here
    For i = 8 To vRws2
        Set vRng2 = .Range("U" & i & "AC" & i)      '< -- Here
    Next d
```

---

A couple of other issues at a glance

1. Declare your `MS Wall Summary Weekly View` sheet variable right away and remove the `.Activate` line at the start
2. You are not using your `With` block all the way. Your `Range` properties need to be prefixed with a dot
3. You declared `d8` as a range but you set it equal to `d`. You may need to revisit what the goal is here as this is not a valid range
4. Building a multiple-cells range may be easier using the `Cells` property (**On Error 2: above**). You can use `.Range(.Cells(i, "U"), .Cells(i, "AC"))` instead (note the qualifier dot, going against the `With ActiveSheet` block variable)

Comment: "you swapped the number 1 with letter l", is backwards.